# Запись введенных данных в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, запрос

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть таблица с товарами (`test`). И я создал вторую таблицу, для записи туда дополнительных параметров товара (`extendtovar`).
Так как список большой, и хочется добавить все быстро, в панели администрирования создал такой код, который выводит мне список всех товаров, и поле для ввода текста дополнительного параметра `pages`

```
 $todb = $mysqli->query('SELECT 
  test.id AS id,
  test.name AS name,
  extendtovar.id AS id2,
  extendtovar.pages AS pages
  FROM test LEFT JOIN extendtovar 
  ON test.id = extendtovar.id 
  WHERE test.remainder > 0');
  while ($row = $todb->fetch_array())
  { echo $row[id];
      echo $row[name];
       echo '<input type="text" name="text" value="'.$row[pages].'"><br>';
  }
```

По моей логике, после ввода данных во все строки, нужно их записать обратно в таблицу. Я добавил кнопку

```
<form method="post" class="update">
<input value="update" class="submit" type="submit" name="submit"><br><br><br>
</form>
```

и никак не могу понять какой правильный запрос написать при нажатии на нее.
Нужно использовать Update? Но как записать массово это.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, у вас для формы нет атрибута `action`. Значить её не обрабатывает ни один скрипт.

Во-вторых, php поддерживает массивы в POST и GET данных. Для этого достаточно в имени input'а добавить `[]`. Например:

```
<input name="input[0][title]" type="text">
<input name="title[0]" type="text">
```

Comment: *Значить её не обрабатывает ни один скрипт.* -- не совсем. Запрос будет послан на тот же URL, на котором находится форма.